# NoneType object is not iterable while iterating on image and mask dataset

Tags: python, numpy, nonetype

I am trying to plot dataset using `matplotlib` like this:

```py
for i in range(5):
    image, mask = dataset[np.random.randint(0,len(dataset))]
    plot2x2Array(image, mask)
```

Stacktrace of the error I get:

```sh
<ipython-input-50-ae8dda81ef7f> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(5):
----> 2   image, mask = dataset[np.random.randint(0, len(dataset))]
      3   plot2x2Array(image, mask)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: It seems that after the value retreived from the index in dataset is a`NoneType` which  you have tried to unpack. _Only iterables can be unpacked_. You can entries in your dataset where the value is `None` or fill it

Comment: Could you tell us the datatype of the variable `dataset`? I suspect it is a `pandas.DataFrame`. In that case, could you also include the shape of the dataset?

Comment: Hi, from the Error Message, I assume the whole problem is independent of matplotlib. Can you create an MWE (minimal working example, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258849/3734258 )?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule yes, your clarification was helpful

Comment: @Ralf I'm including rest of the code

Comment: @ralf '#train image + mask data
train_mask = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
#depth data
depth = pd.read_csv('depths.csv')
#training path
train_path = "./"

#list of files
file_list = list(train_mask['id'].values)
#define our dataset using our class
dataset = TGSSaltDataset(train_path, file_list)'

Comment: @tim I am unable to create MWE

Comment: Though problem is solved